# Check if ImageView has ColorFilter applied or not?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

So I am trying to do Likes in my social app and whether to determine if the like was already applied or not I am trying to see over the color filter

So if the post is not liked it will be white otherwise I will execute this line while pressing on it

```
buttonlikesHeart.setColorFilter(Color.rgb( 255,0,0 ));
```

and this works fine but when I want to check if it already has this particular Colorfilter:

```
if(buttonlikesHeart.getColorFilter() == Color.rgb( 255,0,0 )){

}
```

it tells me == cannot be applied to Colorfilter and int ?

and if I do

```
if(buttonlikesHeart.getColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255,0,0 ))){

}
```

it tells me getColorFilter in ImageView cannot be applied to int

solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are applying this in an ImageView Not a Button.

"buttonlikesHeart" it should be an ImageView

```
 if(imageView.getColorFilter() == null)
                    {
                        Log.i("The Image has no Filter", "No filter");
                        //Your rest of code here.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("The Image is Filtered", "Filtered");
                        //Your rest of code here.
                    }
```